# Compact perturbation of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$A-B$ is a compact linear operator on a Banach space, such that $B$ is boubded and invertible and $A$ is bounded and not invertible. I need to show that there exists a $v\ne 0$ such that $Av=0$.

I know that if $A-B$ is compact then $\sigma(A-B)=\sigma_p (A-B)\cup\{0\}$. How can I use this fact to show that $0\in\sigma_p(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $A-B=K$, with $K$ compact. Since $B$ is invertible, this is equivalent to $$AB^{-1}+I=KB^{-1}.$$
This new decomposition still retains that $AB^{-1}$ is non-invertible, and $KB^{-1}$ is compact.

So $AB^{-1}=-I+KB^{-1}$. Since $A$ is not invertible, $$0\in\sigma(AB^{-1})=\sigma(-I+KB^{-1})=-1+\sigma(KB^{-1}).$$ It follows that $1\in\sigma(KB^{-1})$. But $KB^{-1}$ is compact, so $1$ is an eigenvalue: there exists nonzero $w$ such that $KB^{-1}w=w$. Thus, with $v=B^{-1}w$,
$$
Av=AB^{-1}w=-w+KB^{-1}w=-w+w=0.
$$